# Glossary column header

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to add headers to the columns in the glossary, but I don't manage to make it work. Does anyone have any idea how to add column headers? The code below change the title of the glossary to "Main", but does not give me the column headers I expected.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\glossarystyle{tree}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Main}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Acronyms}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Description}
\renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Page}

\newglossaryentry{test}{
name={test},
description={Description of test}
}

\newglossaryentry{test2}
{
name={test2},
description={Description of test2}
}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\printglossary
\vspace{5cm}
\gls{test}, \gls{test2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a style that support headers, for example `long3colheader`. BTW, the command `\glossarystyle` has been superseded by `\setglossarystyle`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
\renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Main}
\renewcommand*{\entryname}{Acronyms}
\renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Description}
\renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Page}

\newglossaryentry{test}{
name={test},
description={Description of test}
}

\newglossaryentry{test2}
{
name={test2},
description={Description of test2}
}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}
\printglossary

\vspace{5cm}
\gls{test}, \gls{test2}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @user1570707 you're welcome